Hyperref with citation in figure caption not working in Spanish
I have found an edge case in which the hyperref package does not work with the pagebackref option when using spanish language.
The situation in which this happens is when I cite bibliography in the caption of a figure, and then I print the list of figures, while using the pagebackref option in hyperref.
I have here a MWE in which this behavior is seen:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,spanish]{memoir}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla, es-notilde]{babel}  % Your usual Spanish setup

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@book{me01,
    author    = {Me Myself},
    title     = {This Should Be Blackened},
    publisher = {August House},
    date      = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\usepackage[pdftex,
            pagebackref,
            pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    {
        \frontmatter
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \newpage
        \HUGE My title
    }
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    
    \mainmatter
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \part{Theory Motivation}
    \chapter{Test}

    \blindtext

    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Descripción de la figura\cite{me01}}  % Normal citation
    \end{figure}

    \backmatter
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{my.bib}

\end{document}

This has to be solved by either deactivating the pagebackref option, or by not citing anything in figures' captions. Given that I do not want to do any of those possible solutions, because it's very inconvenient, do you know any way I in which I can circumvent this problem?
The error I get is:
main2.tex:67: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 7.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.67     \bibliography{my.bib}
                              
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 7.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> ...main2.tex
                                                  
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...main2.tex
                                                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Of course that if I change the babel language to English (british for example), everything works fine.
If this is a bug, do you know if it's coming from hyperref or babel?
Thanks a lot!
Cheers,
Fran

welcome! my attempts to compile this produce errors, but not the error you're asking about. you want \bibliography{my} without the extension.

spanish surrounds roman page numbers with non-expandable formatting commands, and this breaks with backref as it tries to create page links from page numbers.
Either disable the spanish page numbers completly with the option es-lcroman or try this in the preamble after loading hyperref:
\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
\long\def\hyper@page@backref#1#2#3{{\def\protect{}\Hy@pdfstringtrue\xdef\@gtempa{#1}}\hyperlink{page.\@gtempa}{#1}}
\let\backrefxxx\hyper@page@backref
\NewCommandCopy\ories@scroman\es@scroman
    \DeclareRobustCommand\es@scroman[1]{\protect\texorpdfstring{\ories@scroman{#1}}{\text_uppercase:n{#1}}}
\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff   


I cannot thank you enough for this! Easy, simple, and directly solved my issue. Thanks a lot! :)

There appears to be an unresolved conflict between hyperref's pagebackref option, babel/spanish (esp. its use of small-cap roman numerals instead of lowercase roman numerals for displaying page numbers), and the use of \cite commands in the arguments of \caption statements.
The quickest solution that's also robust I can think of is to change the caption statements from the form
\caption{Descripción de la figura\cite{me01}}

to
\caption[Descripción de la figura]{Descripción de la figura\cite{me01}}

i.e., to provide an optional argument without a \cite directive. The optional argument will be used for the entry in the List of Figures and List of Tables, respectively. That way, the pagebackref page numbers will point correctly to the page where the \cite command is first encountered in the \mainmatter portion of the text, rather than to the List of Figures and List of Tables, which are typically located in the \frontmatter portion of the document.
I would also apply a few additional changes to your code to make it more streamlined and robust, along the following lines:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{memoir}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{me01,
    author    = {Me Myself},
    title     = {This Should Be Blackened},
    publisher = {August House},
    year      = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex % pdfLaTeX is in use
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\else % either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX is in use
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi

\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla, es-notilde]{babel}

\usepackage{subcaption} 

%\usepackage{cite}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
% Unlike 'unsrt', 'unsrtnat' knows what to do with 'url' fields

%\usepackage{notoccite} % do you need this?
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe,blindtext}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks at arbitrary locations in argument of '\url'
%\usepackage{filecontents} % not needed nowadays

\usepackage[%pdftex, % not needed
            pagebackref,pdfusetitle,
            colorlinks,allcolors=blue,linktocpage % new
           ]{hyperref}

% optional
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\mdseries}

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    %\pagenumbering{roman} % redundant
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    {\centering
     \HUGE 
     My title
     \par}

    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    

    \mainmatter
    %\pagenumbering{arabic} % redundant

    \part{Theory Motivation}
    \chapter{Test}

    \blindtext

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption[Descripción de la figura]%
            {Descripción de la figura \cite{me01}}
    \label{fig:me01}
    \end{figure}

    \backmatter
    %\clearpage
    %\phantomsection
    %\nocite{*}
    \bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}

